# How to resize the box on a Menu Item when hovered over

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF application and have some menu items on a menu, however when i hover over he menu item the highlighted box is not the same size as the writing, how do i either remove the box (make it invisible) or change the size of the box (Preferred). Here is my menu item in XAML.

```
<MenuItem Header="Help" Foreground="#FF7E8385" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="18"
Margin="25,12,0,0"/>
```

[image]

Comment: The `box` would be your menu item style border, and either way, you'll have to edit it.

What are you using? some framework? or is it your code?

Answer (score 1):

you can customize your Menu and MenuItem using ControlTemplate.Please go through below link and have some reference.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747082%28v=vs.85%29.aspx